# complex preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to convert this code into single line preg_replace() to avoid repeating of the code? Thanks in advance.

```html
$string = preg_replace('/[^ \w]+\'/', ' ', $string); // Removes special chars except spaces and single quote.
$string = preg_replace('/\'/', '!', $string); //Replace single quotes to exclamation
$string = preg_replace('/-/', '^', $string);
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); //Change spaces to -
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '!-', $string)
```

Comment: line 1 & 4 is redundant. You can replace to '-' already in the first one (and put line 3 on top)

Comment: Nice, Thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks it works!